# distribution of the index of the maximum of n correlated standard normal variates

Tags: probability

Given $n$ dependent standard normal random variables ($x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$, with known correlation matrix), what is the probability that $x_i$ will be the maximum?

Answer (score 0):

Given $X_1,X_2\ldots,X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf\mu,\mathbf\Sigma)$, then $\Pr(X_i\ge X_j \forall j) = \Pr(X_j-X_i\le0\; \forall j)$. The random variables $Z_j=(X_j-X_i)$ also have a multivariate normal distribution. If we create an indicator matrix $\mathbf{I}$ such that $\mathbf Z = \mathbf{I}\mathbf X$ then $\mathbf Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu',\mathbf\Sigma')$ with $\mathbf\mu'=\mathbf I\mathbf\mu$ and $\mathbf\Sigma' = \mathbf I\mathbf\Sigma\mathbf I^T$. So the desired probability is the multivariate normal cumulative distribution function evaluated at zero: $\Phi^{n-1}_{\mathbf\mu',\mathbf\Sigma'}(0)$. Unfortunately there are no analytical solutions for $n>3$, but numerical approximations are available.